# Show PDF File Selection using Intent

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent

The following code shows all files but I select another format file it returns error.

```
Intent selectionintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            selectionintent.setType("application/pdf");
            selectionintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

            List activitiesPDF = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(selectionintent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            boolean isIntentSafePDF = activitiesPDF.size() > 0;
            if (isIntentSafePDF)
                startActivityForResult(selectionintent, CODE_RESULT);
            else
                Toast.makeText(UpdateFileActivity.this, "Only select pdf files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

onActivity Result:

```
 if (requestCode == CODE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String file = uri.toString();
        File f = new File(file);
        if (file.startsWith("content://")) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else if (file.startsWith("file://")) {
            displayName = f.getName();
        }
        filetext.setText(displayName);
    }
```

I want to show only pdf files

Comment: akhilesh code was work when the file name contains .pdf          the file has no extension then it couldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the list of pdf files from mobile (I used intent but it not getting all the pdf files so I used this approach)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    boolean result = marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForReadExtertalStorage();
    if (result) {
        getPdfFromExternalStorage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    } else {
        try {
            marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForReadExtertalStorage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} else {
    getPdfFromExternalStorage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
}
```

Search pdf files from device

```
private void getPdfFromExternalStorage(File folder) {
    if (folder != null) {
        if (folder.listFiles() != null) {
            for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    //.pdf files
                    if (file.getName().contains(".pdf")) {
                        Log.d("filePath-------", "" + file.getPath());
                    }
                } else {
                    getPdfFromExternalStorage(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (file.getName().contains(".pdf")) {
                        Log.d("filePath-------", "" + file.getPath());
                    }   already tried this some pdf files has no extension

Comment: If u dont mine i have one doubt: Why you using M(marshmallow) permission . my file inside of internal storage

Comment: Oh k. and my file has no extension